# Using BufferedReader to print out data separated by commas

Tags: java, csv, bufferedreader

I need to print out values from certain columns in a csv file.

[image]

Below is an example of the data. There is a comma in one field and I have tried putting in the commas like; `System.out.println("\"" + b[0] + "\",\"" +b[4] + "\",\""+ b[6] + "\"");` But this confuses the code and mixes up the commas within the csv file value.

Code looks like this;

```
"Van","Truck",""Car"," new""
```

I want to display the data like this:

```
"Car,new", "Van", "Truck"
```

**Note the comma at the end of Car**

Below is my code. How can I get it to ignore print out and ignore the comma after Car instead of putting double quotes around it?

thanks in advance

```
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sr));
          String splitBy = ",";
          String line = br.readLine();
          while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            String[] b = line.split(splitBy);
            System.out.println("\"" + b[0] + "\",\"" +b[4] + "\",\""+ b[6] + "\"");
          }
          br.close();
        }
      }
```

Comment: Replace `System.out.println(b[0] +b[4]+b[6]);` by `System.out.println("\"" + b[0] + "\",\"" +b[4] + "\",\""+ b[6] + "\"");`?

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear in my question and have since updated the question to read better. Your above code is something I have tried but because one value in the column reads 'Car,' adding in the commas confuse the code and it does not output accordingly

Comment: What you need to do is csv parsing and not comma splitting. Yes the name means comma-separated values. But a value like `Car,` in a CSV file is usually enclose in quotes like `"Car,"` to escape content commas from separator commas. So, its best to use a CSV parser for such things, rather than parsing all standards yourself.

Comment: @Kris  Is there a way to ignore the `'` in the csv file when printing out the data?